# Get the product of two values from two different tables

Tags: sql

If anyone can help me figure out where I am going wrong with this SQL that would be great. Please see my attempt to answer it below. I have answer how I think it should be answered but I am very confused by the exam advice below, which says I should use a SUM function? I have googled this and I do not see how a SUM function can help here when I need get the product of two values in this case. Or am I missing something major?

Question: TotalValue is a column in Order relation that contains derived data representing total value (amount) of each order. Write a SQL SELECT statement that computes a value for this column.

My answer:

```
SELECT Product.ProductPrice * OrderLine.QuantityOrdered AS Total_Value
FROM Product,
     OrderLine
GROUP BY Product;
```

Advice from exam paper: 
 *[This is a straightforward question. Tip: you need to use the SUM function. Also, note that you can take the sum of various records set using the GROUP BY clause.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuQLG.png)*

Comment: Hi Effie, contrary to what you may heard/expect, Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.  Typically, only questions showing effort involving active problems get any assistance here.  That being said, have you tried something yet?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen She included an answer.

Comment: @Eggsalad No, that's a link to some table data, there is no sign a query anywhere.  Incidentally, I enjoy eating egg salad, and in fact had that for lunch a few days ago :-)

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Another tip: Create the tables, add data. Try JOIN. Try GROUP BY etc! That's how you learn SQL!

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Haha! You are clearly highly intelligent.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My answer attempt was written in my question. Comes after "My answer:" and then there is a SQL query.

Comment: I am going to edit my answer to be more clear about what exactly my confusion with the question is.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks a lot for the feedback. That was from an exam paper from a few years ago - maybe it is out of date. The reason I am so confused by this is the Exam Advice tells me that I should use the SUM function... whereas I interpret that TotalValue is a product of Product.ProductPrice and OrderLine.QuantityOrdered. Cannot see how a SUM function would be useful. I am very happy to try using JOIN for this. I was just confused by the exam advice given. Thought I was missing something major.

Answer (score 0):

Ok your question became a lot clearer once I clicked on the the hyperlink (blue text).

Each order is going to be made up of a quantity of 1 or more products.
So there could be 3 Product A and 5 Product B etc.

So you have to get the total for each product which is your Price * Quantity, but then you need to add them all together which is where the SUM comes in.

Example:

```
3 * ProductA Price (e.g. €5) = 15
5 * ProductB Price (e.g. €4) = 20
```

Total Value = 35

So you need to use the Product, Order and OrderLine tables.

Something like (I haven't tested it):

```
SELECT SUM(Product.ProductPrice * OrderLine.QuantityOrdered) FROM Product, Order, OrderLine
WHERE Order.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID
AND Product.ProductID = OrerLine.ProductID
GROUP BY Order.OrderID
```

This should return rows containing the totalValue for each order - the GROUP BY clause causes the SUM to SUM over each group - not the entire rows.

For a single order you would need add (before the GROUP BY) "AND Order.OrderID = XXXXX" where XXXXX is the actual orders OrderId.

Comment: By the way, it's a good idea to avoid having a table called Order as it can lead to confusion with the ORDER BY clause.(Notice Order got turned blue above because ORDER is a reserved word in SQL)